# QGIS for geophysical surveying?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to make 30x30 and 20x20 grid layouts with co-ordinate points in the corners. These points then need to be relayed to a GPS to be able to set the grids out in person and then survey them. The results are then needed to be uploaded and georeferenced to a basemap.

(Is QGIS able to easily do this and how simple is it to provide .CSV points for the GPS since I am not sure that it takes .GPX data)

---

I have managed to make a grid and points, I know the points have and ID, is it possible to make this ID start at 1?

Also can I make the ID numbers appear next to the points?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Here you are asking a broad question and calling for people to share experiences and recommendations i.e. enter into a discussion.

Comment: I have edited the question, is it more acceptable now? New to site sorry. @PolyGeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the tool Regular Points? I believe this is what you are looking for.

It can be found under Vector - Research Tools - Regular Points...

Comment: Very new to all of this, when it asks me to input x and y co-ordinates how do I know what to input? Thanks

Comment: I've managed to input co-ordinates, worked that part out, just need to number the points now. @adam-thom

Comment: Is it small enough for you to add a field and manually edit  the numbers in?

Comment: Managed to make the regular points tool work adequately. Just let the ID show for the points and had them numbered.
Updating the attribute containing the ID using the **Field Calculator** and using expression:
`$rownum`
This reset the number ID after I'd deleted the points that I didn't need. Advice from @Joseph